# Graph only a part of JSON output

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Let me start by saying that I'm starting to use javascript and jquery, so i don't know much about them, that being said here it's the question:

I'm generating a JSON string that take the state of the pins of an arduino. The string it's in this:

`{
    "02":0,
    "03":0,
    "04":0,
    "05":0,
    "06":0,
    "07":0,
    "08":0,
    "09":0,
    "10":0,
    "11":0,
    "12":0,
    "13":0,
    "14":756,
    "15":745,
    "16":722,
    "17":679,
    "18":634,
    "19":494
}`

the first part of the string (02 to 13) belongs to the digital pins, which i don't need, the second part (14 to 19), are the analogs pins, this are the ones that i need to graph
, other thing its that i program the JSON string to update every 5 sec, so thats the thing that i need to graph, but i really don't know how to do it

UPDATE (11/10/2013)

Let me clarify my question, I'm making a mobile web page using jquery and jquery mobile, in that web page, i'm taking the data that's coming from an arduino, which it's the temperature, i was able to show the value of the temperature, but i like to make a graph of those values (temperature vs time), and show them in the page. Like i said before, i really know nothing about web development, so i don't know how to implement that graph. this its how i show temperature

```
function value_update(data) {
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
    if(parseInt(index)=>13) {
    $('#P'+index).text(((5*value*100)/1024).toFixed(1)+" °C");
    }
});
```

And this it's how i put it in the html

```
<label><b>TEMPERATURE A0</b></label>
<span class="inputvalue" name="P14" id="P14">0</span>
```

Please help !!!!

Comment: so what's the question? how to make a graph or how to remove the digital pins from the json?

Comment: For the second part of your question (which is a separate question in itself) google "jquery graph". There are several good graphing libraries out there some of which are very lightweight and simple to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter the data you can do:

```
var data = { "02":0, "03":0, "04":0, "05":0, "06":0, "07":0, "08":0, "09":0, "10":0, "11":0, "12":0, "13":0, "14":756, "15":745, "16":722, "17":679, "18":634, "19":494 };
var toGraph = {};
$.each(data,function(key,value){
    if(key >= 14){
        toGraph[key] = value;
    }
});

//toGraph now holds the wanted data: 
console.log(toGraph); //Outputs Object {14: 756, 15: 745, 16: 722, 17: 679, 18: 634, 19: 494}
```

Comment: thanks for you response, but i really need more clarification on you answer, like how i can put it in a html page and how to implement it, i'm sorry about this, but like i said before i'm really just starting to learn about web development and dinamic content.

Comment: @user2865808 The above code creates a new object with the data that has a key larger or equal to 14, that's the best the I could do since from your question it's not clear what help do you need, please update your question with your current code and a clear sentence of what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the first part, by two methods.

The first one is creating a string of values, and the using .substring, getting exactly the values you are looking for.

The second one, and probably the best one, is to store all the values in an array, and then extract the values you are looking for thanks to array value positions. If you, in the end need a string of values, you can convert the array values to a string. In terms of data flexibility, I'd say array to string is the way to go, just in case you want to do something else with the values in the future.

For a custom refresh setup, a simple [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) will do the trick.

For a beginner course in Javascript, I recommend to check codeacademy.

Comment: The data in the OP is not a string but a JSON object